# Flask: How to prevent to go to login page when already logged in?

Tags: python, flask, authorization, flask-login

I have been doing the Flask Web Development Book by Miguel Grinberg, and just finished up with the authorization blueprint. Though, I am having an issue that if I am already logged in, I can still put the url of the login page and go there. How can I prevent this in Flask?

While using Django, I came up with django-braces library which helps to do this, any such alternative available in Flask?

Comment: Just redirect the user if already logged in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Redirect](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors) users who are logged in navigating to the login page.

To check if they are already logged in, examine the [`current_user`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.current_user) proxy. Note that logged-in users will have [`current_user.is_authenticated()`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#your-user-class) equal True, while users who aren't logged in will have the method return False.

You have two options for the destination: back to their previous page with `redirect(request.referrer)` or to one of your other pages with `redirect(url_for('view_name'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [current_user.is_authenticated()](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.login_required).