# Can you return a return statement in Python?

Tags: python, return

I'm working on a web application and I'm creating a login & authentication form. Some pages should be off-limits if you are logged in (e.g. the login form), and I'm trying to create a systematic way of doing this.

To do this, I was trying to create a function which would return a return statement. See the code below.

```
def login():
    redirect_to_home_if_logged_in()
    # rest of login page
def register():
    redirect_to_home_if_logged_in()
    # rest of register page
def redirect_to_home_if_logged_in():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        print("squa")
        return return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

I was hoping that the function would return a return statement, so that the login and register pages would return a redirect. Instead I got an error.

Comment: For most web frameworks, there is a standard way of doing stuff like this, you should refer to their documentation for this. Web dev aside, what you seem to be describing is a [Python decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)

Comment: @Dair I tried using decorators but I cannot decorate the login function with a redirect_to_home_if_logged_in because then we are outside of the request and current_user is a NoneType

Comment: It was really hard to understand what the OP expected here. But it seems like what is meant is that, when `login` is called, the `redirect(url_for('home'))` result should be returned. The way this works is, `redirect_to_home_if_logged_in` should just `return` that normally, and then **the calling functions `return` the result from calling `redirect_to_home_if_logged_in`**. That is, there should be *one* `return` in each place. There isn't really a way to ask the general question of how to use functions properly, so I used the closest duplicate I kow of.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot return a `return` statement as such.

A common arrangement is to refactor the code so that the caller takes care of what you return, and relays that back to *its* caller.

Another approach is via callbacks. Something like this:

```
def bar():
    def foo():
        return "ick"
    return foo
```

Here, the return value from `bar` is a function object `foo`. This requires the caller of `bar` to know this and agree to call `foo()` at some later point in time when the value is actually required. (You could often also use a lambda in these circumstances; Python predictably calls this type of value a "callable".)

As noted by @Dair in a comment already, what you are actually trying to accomplish is probably already covered by a completely different mechanism by whichever web framework you are probably already using. [Here's Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059694/flask-how-to-prevent-to-go-to-login-page-when-already-logged-in) and [here's Django.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320581/django-redirect-logged-in-users-from-login-page)